# PHP-String remove everything before and including " - "

Tags: php, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I can get the variaation name with:

```
$variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation['variation_id']);                                    
variation_name = $variation_obj->get_name();
```

This gives me an output with the following pattern: " - " but I just need the `Variation` attribute output. Examples are: 
"Refresh Spray - 250 ml"
"Refresh Spray - 500 ml"
"Refresh Spray - 1 l"

How can I remove the " - " and everything in front of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the last occurrence and get the string after that:

```
$name = substr($variation_name, strrpos($variation_name, '-'));
```

and when you want to remove any whitespaces use trim afterwards:

```
$name = trim($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various different methods for doing this kind of thing but my trick is the code below.

```
<?php

$var = "blahblahblah - hello"; // put here your variable containing the "-"
$var = explode("-", $var); // cuts the string into pieces at the "-" and removes the "-"
$var = $var[0]; // grabs the part before the "-"
$var = $var."-"; // adds the "-" again, remove this part if you don't want the "-"

echo($var);

?>
```

this should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything before "-" including it:

```
$str_after = preg_replace("#.+\s?-#","",$variation_name);
```

But if you want to remove everything after including the "-":

```
$str_before = preg_replace("#-\s?.+#","",$variation_name);
```